# Protect data in docker container

Tags: docker

Because user can access docker container to copy/insert new files, I want to protect my data and don't allow them do this. so is there anyway to lock this door or if they want, they have to input username/password ?

Let me explain more about my concern. I installed my website in my Raspberry Pi by using docker container and copy this image to my customer. They can access their Raspberry pi and the problem is they can copy the website in their Raspberry via

docker exec -it mywebsite /bin/bash
or 
sudo docker cp mywebsite:/usr/src/app/example.html .

so is there any way to lock this door ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use [`phusion/baseimage-docker`](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker). It has ssh feature and `setuser` option.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're asking, as it's currently not clear; Is "user" a user on the host? In the container? Are you distributing your image to users to run on their own system? etc. If you can provide more information, then it's more likely you get the answer you're looking for

Comment: I edited my question to add more information. any idea ? thanks

Comment: Where is the data you want to protect from modifications coming from? If it's a volume, you can expose it read-only.

Comment: all I want are don't allow them copy source code of the website

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking about, but I assume you want to prevent the users on the host from accessing some Docker container, right?

If you mean by **User** word, a user **on the host**, then you are already **protected**! as long as the user is not `root`, `sudo` member, or `Docker` member, then you are absolutely safe!

Comment: I don't know enough about docker, but suppose the following scenario: You installed a docker image on a server that you are his sudo. Then another person move the server's harddisk  to another computer that he his sudo. Could that person on the other computer to use his sudo to have full access to the docker image?

Comment: @SaidbakR, I can imagine yes, he will have full access to the Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You can commit  a docker container with container id and image name. (save container's current state) After that you can run that image with image name. Here an example from docker docs.

> ```
> $ docker ps
> ```
>
> CONTAINER ID IMAGE  COMMAND    CREATED   STATUS      PORTS   NAMES
>
> c3f279d17e0a        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25
>   hours                            desperate_dubinsky 
>   197387f1b436      ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25
>   hours                            focused_hamilton
>
> ```
> $ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3
> ```
>
> f5283438590d
>
> ```
> $ docker images
> ```
>
> REPOSITORY                        TAG                 ID              CREATED             SIZE
>
> svendowideit/testimage            version3            f5283438590d        16 seconds ago      335.7 MB
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d svendowideit/testimage:version3
> ```